# Force browsers to reload cache WITHOUT server side code

Tags: javascript

I need the ability to force reload of cache when a user goes to my page (for a few reasons) and I have seen ways to do this with server side code but I am using a hosted CMS and do not have the ability to use server side code. Is there a way to do this with javascript alone?

Or should I use something like `myjavascript.js?=v1` on all of my css and js files?

what is the best method?

Comment: So you want js to put in the page to reload itself without using the cached version. Is that correct?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript

Comment: I want the entire site to be reloaded. I do not want a cached version of my site being used for a bit (I have a few reasons but I am not going to explain here)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When a browser visits a site only one page is loaded at a time. Are you trying to clear the browser cache, or just ensure that a cached version of any page on the site is never used?

Comment: Cache is managed by the server environment. You need to look into ways to defeat a server's cache protocols, and incorporate that into the client-side request to the server.

Comment: I want to ensure that if a person has visited the page before the cached version is not used and they are forced to download a new version of the site (or the page they are visiting)

Comment: @Jared how is this done, can you give me an example?

Comment: You are trying to prevent browser caching? There are dozens of ways to do that all with different pros and cons. This is a duplicate of dozens of questions on the site. Just search for "prevent browser caching"

Comment: That would depend on how the server was managing the server environment. Some answers have already been provided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an elegant way to force browsers to reload cached CSS/JS files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: Tell the user to press Ctrl + F5 by themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an HTML meta tag, something like

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: This won't reliably work in all situations, but is one option.