# How do I simulate ctrl-F5 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the refresh should discard the cache, how to do it with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear the cache in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

Answer (score 28):

**2024 Update:** A comment rightly points out that my original answer from 12 and a half years ago no longer applies, except for in FireFox.  This got me thinking about why one would ever want to programmatically trigger a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.  The answer, of course, is that a linked script has updated, but the browser is serving an out-of-date cached version of the script.

You can avoid most of the need for reloading the page with proper use of cache-busting.  A browser's cache uses the resource's URL as the cache key.  So, when a linked script file changes, you can tweak the URL you request in your `<script>` tag's `src` attribute so that you request a brand-new URL, and the browser won't find the new URL in its cache and it's forced to fetch the file fresh from the server.  The easy way to do this is to append a version string to the URL's querystring, and change that string whenever the resource changes.

Eg, instead of requesting `style.css`, `script.js`, and `image.png`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
<img src="image.png" />
```

You would append the version string and request `style.css?v1.0.0`, `script.js?v1.0.0`, and `image.png?v1.0.0`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v1.0.0" />
<script src="script.js?v1.0.0"></script>
<img src="image.png?v1.0.0" />
```

If you are serving your HTML dynamically from the server, your server-side code can inject that value.  If you are serving static HTML files, you'll want to write a script that will update your HTML files whenever the code changes in a linked resource.

The above is fine to update cached scripts.  But, the one time you might still need to programmatically reload a page is if the server has updated shortly after the page was loaded, and your page fetches data from the server.  In that case, your server-side code might be expecting the client to have the latest client-side code running.  So, you'll need to reload the page to update the client code.

In order to detect that the server has changed, update your server code to include a version string in its API responses.  Then, when you get a response from the server, you can compare the API version with the loaded version, and reload the page when you detect the server has updated.

First, find the `<script>` tag and read its `src` property, to find the client script's version:

```js
const scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='?v']");
// the currently executing script should be the last script in the document so far
const currentScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
const scriptURL = new URL(currentScript.src);
const scriptVersion = scriptURL.search.slice(1); // slice off the leading '?'
```

Then, in your code that calls your API, check the version from the API response and compare it to the script version.  Reload the page if the versions differ:

```js
async function getData(args) {
    const res = await fetch("/api/data?" + new URLSearchParams(args));
    const data = await res.json();
    if (data.apiVersion !== scriptVersion) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Passing `true` to `location.reload()` only does something in FireFox; other browsers ignore it.  But, with cache-busting URLs in place on all linked resources, it should be good enough.  That is, the top level page should be fetched from the server, and it will have cache-busting URLs on all of its linked resources, so it should work the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.  But, just in case I'm wrong and you find that `location.reload()` isn't enough to reload the top-level page from the server, just use the same cache-busting principles as before to really force the page to reload:

```js
location.replace("?" + apiVersion);
```

Or, if your URL already has a querystring:

```js
location.replace(location.search + "&" + apiVersion);
```

Comment: As he wants jQuery: `jQuery.globalEval( "location.reload(true);" );`

Comment: *Only supported in Firefox

Answer (score 7):

The ability to modify the browser cache is outside the scope of what jQuery can do.

Comment: What do you think of @gilly3's answer?

Comment: `location.reload(true)` only forces a reload from the server of the *page* data. It does not modify the browser cache and does not affect whether *other* documents (such as scripts, stylesheets, or images) referenced from the page are loaded from the cache or not.

Comment: According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx), `location.reload(true)` behaves the same as CTRL + f5.

Comment: That's a good resource, at least for IE. I'm not sure I would expect all other browsers to behave consistently, so using a nonce value ensures the correct content is loaded.

Comment: +1 since this mentions jQuery, which is what the OP specifically asked about, even if it wasn't an actual "answer" per se.  I would suggest gilly3's answer above is as good as it gets from a javascript perspective.

Comment: Wait a moment, what about `jQuery.globalEval( "location.reload(true);" );`

Answer (score 4):

This won't be possible.

Just increment the version number to your javascript reference like this every time you wish to force a fresh download:

```
<script language="javascript" src="scripts/script.js?ver=2"></script>
```

Just to clarify, the appended `ver` parameter has no intrinsic value on the script `src` attribute as Slomojo pointed out. It was merely a way to address the problem of a forced file reload and also keep a neat versioning system.

Comment: -1 - This reads as if "version number" is some sort of intrinsic parameter of a script src uri. Which of course it isn't. In addition, the version number of the script.js isn't necessarily being incremented, you just want to force the server to throw you a fresh copy, so name your parameter something more meaningful, e.g. `reload=RANDOM`, `flush=RANDOM` etc. This way you are communicating more about the underlying principle, ie. That the browser and server see a new uri and thus avoid the cache.

Comment: No it doesn't. `ver` can just be something you have named, it could be anything, like `reload`. The end result is the same, the script will be freshly downloaded. Anyway my answer is inappropriate on the grounds of wanting to refresh from JavaScript.

Comment: What it infers is the important thing, hopefully you realise I'm not suggeting that *you* think it's an intrinsic parameter, I'm simply pointing out that a novice may well get that impression.

Comment: I am also merely saying `ver` is a good practice to use alongside the the new file being served, as why are you wanting a fresh download? Chances are the file has been modified, therefore it truly is a new revision, or version.

Comment: Yes perhaps a novice might think it has some magical value in the script src uri. But I see it a common practice, anyway I might delete the post as it's really irrelevant to reloading via JavaScript.

Comment: You could just have easily added `?rand=243234`. This in combination with @gilly3's answer might work.

Comment: Yep totally, just thought it would be more meaningful to use a version numbering system as well. But sure, rand, whatever, anything works. (Yay I'm brought into the positive again, lol, thanks fudgey)

Comment: +1 for the update. I think leaving this here is helpful. If this wasn't such a novice question I think it wouldn't make any difference having `ver` since you could assume more prior knowledge, but searches for this are likely to bring beginners.

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually address the OP's original question.  If I understand it correctly, this question is aimed at the page cache and is looking for a way to simulate the CTRL+F5 browser behavior, NOT how to make sure a specific resource isn't cached.  These two things are very different.

Comment: Yes, but I'm reading between the lines.... most likely, he is suffering from particular .JS and/or .CSS files caching. I'm pretty sure even location.reload(true) doesn't refresh these from the server properly, it refetches the "page" from the server yes, but doesn't serve you a non-cached copy of some of the resources, I'm pretty sure..

Comment: Oh, I could be wrong, https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/static-file-cache-busting seems to indicate it bypasses cache and pulls down any resource files from the server too.

Answer (score -4):

You can detect ctrl+F5 using following code

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116 && e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('ctrl + F5');//HEHEEE
    }
});
```

Comment: While certainly correct syntactically, this answer is unrelated to the question.