# Javascript: Clear cache on redirect

Tags: javascript, caching, cookies

I can use `location.reload(true)` to refresh the page and refetch the page. I want to redirect the user to a new URL and clear the cache.

More specifically, I have a "Clear all cookies" button that redirects the user to the homepage after being clicked. I want the homepage to be refreshed.

Comment: What doesn't work that you've tried?

Comment: what server-side technology do you use? Something fancy, or just plain HTML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do something like:

```
var loc = window.location.href; // or a new URL
window.location.href = loc + '?n=' + new Date().getTime(); // random number
```

**EDIT:** The only option for reloading static resources (see comment below) would be to append the random number to their URLs server-side by listening for the 'n' query string.

Comment: That would probably work for the page, but not other static resources, e.g. css, js

Comment: Why not `window.location.href = window.location.href + "?15398293843"`?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Just to make it easily readable & understandable. Though it would work either way.

Comment: @MatthewJordan That being said, I'm not sure `location.reload(true)` would help with that either.  Only documentation I've seen on it simply says it refetches the page, says nothing about other resources

Comment: @ElliotBonneville That will only work one time because that number is going to get cached too

Answer (score -4):

Sorry, but you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011617/339852) [clear](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1221243) [the cache](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=26659) with Javascript.

Comment: Completely false, `location.reload(true)` clears cache on reload. Moreover you can append a number to the end of the url, like the other answers suggest.

Comment: The boolean parameter on `location.reload()` exists on Firefox but not any other browsers, so you can't rely on it to work in every case.