# javascript - code to clear the cache on closing the browser

Tags: javascript, session, session-variables, session-cookies

In my web application I wants the java script to clear the cache when the user close the browser.

The javascript should listen to the event and clear the cache.

Can anyone please provide me  sample code or any useful link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically is impossible.
What you can do instead is to tell the browser to not cache the page by using the following meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Here is an article for reference http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881

Comment: I am using jspx. Can you please tell how to add the above code into jspx file

Comment: You need to put them on the html page head section.

Comment: I am using tiles. I have added the above block in the HEAD. After deploying I couldn't see the login page. (I am using Spring-MVC, Spring-ROO with Spring-Security config in my app)

Answer (score 1):

For clearing Cache followiwng link is helpful
[Clear the cache in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

You write some javascript run when you try to close the browser like below

```
window.onbeforeunload = function ()
{
    // write your code here
 }
```

But why do you need to clear cache before closing browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is imposible but I would sugguest you can try the meta tags or you can set a versioning system for instance like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$versionNumber = '';
if(!isset($_SESSION['versionNumber']))
{
    $versionNumber = time() ;
    $_SESSION['versionNumber'] = $versionNumber;
}
else
{
    $versionNumber = $_SESSION['versionNumber'];
}
?>
<script src="home.js?v=<?php echo $versionNumber; ?>" ></script>
```

Comment: This examle in PHP but you can easily convert this into jspx you will need to  take a look at Sessions in JSP

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript its not possible. But using no-cache header you can do it.

Use one of [these methods which work on all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)