# Remove cached pages for entire site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching

First let me start off by saying I did NOT design the site that I am currently supporting.

In the site in question, all html pages are sharing a single javascript page.

I need to update some pages and javascript functionality. The problem is that if I change the functionality and the user does not refresh the page, the javascript errors out (usually because an element has been added to the page and javascript, but the cached page does not have that element).

None of the pages have any coding to prevent caching, so all users are assumed to be using cached pages.

I have added some script to the login page to ensure that the user is getting a fresh copy of the javascript file.

My question is, is there a way to have the javascript file tell the browser to download the latest copy of each page? Every page has an onload() function that exists in the central javascript file.

Comment: I use useless GET-parameter rev for example: /static/js/myscript.js?rev=1.2 and update rev on any change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript