# CSS, Scripts changes not reflect after published in IIS

Tags: css, iis, browser-cache

We have hosted our site that use Mvc application in IIS. We are frequently making some design changes in CSS and Scripts files. So frequently publishing the changes in IIS.

But in client side CSS and Scripts changes are not reflected since its coming form cache. It makes our clinet to hard refresh to get the updated changes.

Is there any way we can do in IIS or hosting machine while publishing, that force to client browser to reload the CSS and Scripts.

Like cleaning the temporary files in IIS or any other way.

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: You can use version in your css and js url. For example,`your css url?v=1`

Comment: can we use that with bundling?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript) can help you.