# js file not updating on client browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, caching, iis

I have a dotnet web application running on a server with IIS7. I have to replace 2 .js files. Some pc's are getting the new file and other are not. I tried to update the time-stamps on the web.config file and those two .js. There is no specific caching set.

How can I force the browser (IE11 in my case) to go get the file from the server and not use the one in the local cache? I won't go on every users pc and clear there cache. I need a better solution and everything I tried so far is not working.

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear the cache in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something unique to the script tag like:

`<script src="myscript.js?version=1.1"></script>`

This will force the browser to fetch the new verison.

Comment: If I don't have access to the code to make that change, is there another option?