# is there a way to clear cache and cookies using javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cookies, microsoft-edge

is there a way to clear cache and cookies using javascript? I am using selenium to run tests in microsoft edge and the tests run in the same session as the previous run (not a new session). Need to figure out how to run on a clean session each time. Right now, there does not seem to be any support in selenium for this.

Comment: You can't clear httpOnly cookies from inside browser....they are protected Question depends on how you set cookies

Answer (score 0):

To clear one cookie use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie), to clear all cookies use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript). You can't clear cache but you can append a version number like its mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome and Firefox, I always used Watir's `browser.cookies.clear` 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Cookies

However, I noticed that this did not work on Edge for some reason. 
So I'm waiting for an answer on this topic (might help you as well)
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14838528/