# How to prevent browser caching in Vue build

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, jquery-ui

I have a VueJS application. When creating a build using a `npm run server`, and load it on server I need to clear the cache every time. I need a way to avoid CSS and JS file cache on the server.

Comment: Lots of discussion on this already. Did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867357/vuejs-browser-caching-production-builds Also, you need to show some code and what attempt you've made.

Comment: Please show your existing webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use session like that :
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
Vue.use(VueSession)
Second you can get session like that :
this.$session.clear()

So, In other to clear session, you can use above code.
In my project i user above code at dashboard.vue on "created()" instance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0aNo.png)