# Issue When Dynamically Removing Script Tags With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created two short javascript files, each containing a `$(document).ready` function that has javascript to detect a button click from the html file that has included it. My main html file has the script tags pointing to each file in the header:

`file1.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wrapper').on('click', '.click_1', function(){
    alert('hello from the first file');
  });
});
```

`file2.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wrapper').on('click', '.click_2', function(){
   alert('hello from the second file');
  });
});
```

My goal, however, is to be able to dynamically remove one of the script tags (the javascript from the second file) from the header, and its functionality along with it. To do so, I created a script in my main html file to remove the target script tag via the `src` attribute. However, while an inspection of the page source reveals that the third script tag has indeed been removed, its functionality remains. For instance, even after clicking the `.remove_2` button, I can still click the `.click_2` button and receive the `"hello from the second file"` alert:

`main.html`:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
         <button class='click_1'>File1</button>
         <button class='click_2'>File2</button>
         <button class='remove_2'>Remove File2</button>
     </div>
   </body>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove_2', function(){
       $('script[src="file2.js"]').remove();
     });
   });
   </script>
 </html>
```

In short, I wish to be able to dynamically remove a script tag so that the javascript in the file that the tag points to no longer has any affect on the html page. However, I have not been able to accomplish this. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Also, is what I am trying to accomplish even possible? Thank you.

Comment: Cache might be there

Comment: @Sinto That is a good idea. How could I clear it of the target javascript file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011605/4229270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an external script does not remove event handlers. They are attached to current document.

A solution can be:

1. remove the script
2. get all html page
3. replace html page with new content

   ```
   $('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove_2', function(){
       $('script[src="file2.js"]').remove();
       var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
       document.open('text/html');
       document.write(html);
       document.close();
   });
   ```

In jQuery, replacing only the header after removing the script:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.remove_2', function(){
    var header = $('html head');
    header.find('script[src="file2.js"]').remove();
    $('html head').replaceWith(header);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution using `document.open('text/html');` worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try [unbinding](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event from the second button before removing it:

```
$('.click_2').unbind("click");
```

Although unbind is now deprecated.  The newer form is 'off':

```
$('.click_2').off( "click", "**" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

That said, you do seem to be using a rather peculiar approach to disable click functionality.