# How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript/CSS files rendered with Jade in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, caching, pug

[Acc. to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files) the best way to introduce `?<version>` number upon every reload. How do I do that when rendering files with Jade in Node.js?

Also what about css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out, I could add time

```
app.configure(function() {
    //...
    app.use(setlocalTime);
    //...
    app.use(app.router);
});
function setlocalTime(req, res, next) {
    app.locals.time = Date.now();
    next();
}
```

```
script(src='/scripts/script.js?'+time)
```