# Is there anyway I can get the time of cached file?

Tags: php, caching

A very simple question, I need time when a file was cached on client's computer.

I want to reload page from server if it's modified after the time of cached file.

Is it possible? I'm completely unaware about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Two common ways are to send `Cache-Control` headers, or include client-side files (like js or css files) with a revision number (`<script type='text/javascript' src='my/file.js?100232'>`). Both approaches allow you to force the client to reload the file, but to answer your question: no, you can't _reliably_ determine the age of a cached file, because it's down to the client to decide how accurate the information it sends to you is

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could embed a timestamp into the html somewhere:

```
<body data-generated="<?php echo time();?>">
```

Then check this against server updated time, via an ajax request:

```
//jquery for berevity

$.get('invalidate_client_cache.php?time='+ $('body').data('generated'), function(data){
    if(data.invalidate){
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

I will leave the php implenentation to you, as i dont know yout requirements, but it could be something like:

```
$clientCacheTime = isset($_GET['time'])? $_GET['time'] : null;
$data=[];
$data['invalidate'] = reloadRequired($clientCacheTime);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That's a nice idea I would say, let me try these. Thanks for a quick response