# Mod_Rewrite variable dynamic directory inside of two static ones

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am trying to force javascript files to reload whenever we as developers update the files. In order to do this we are using the answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7671705/805779 and we think this will work great however I am not sure how to do the mod rewrite. So here is the link I have

```
www.mysite.com/js/v1/myjs.js
```

I need to change it to

```
www.nysite.com/js/myjs.js
```

This is what I have so far but it is not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)$/(.*)$ js/$2 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

After some more testing I found my main issue was not adding .c to my IfModule, with that in mind the following is "partially" working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)/(.*)$ /css/$2 [L,NC,R]
    RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)/(.*)$ /js/$2 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

This works for my classic example

```
www.mysite.com/js/v1/myjs.js => www.nysite.com/js/myjs.js
```

However this does not work if more then one variable are involved. aka

```
www.mysite.com/js/v1/min/pages/myjs.js
```

My version number v1 will always be directly after the root folder so js/v1 or css/v1 and I want to remove the v1 and keep everything after it

Comment: Why not just version control the file (i.e. `myjs_v1.js`, `myjs_v2.js`, etc.)?  This is typically a more scalable strategy, especially when you want to start doing things like storing your static assets on a CDN.  This also allows you to set really long expires headers on that content, aiding in browser-side caching. It also make rollbacks really easy (you just change the HTML to refer back to old file and browser will do the right thing).

Comment: Because as stated in the answer I linked above some browsers and proxies will not read ? variables and cause users to still have outdated files. This way guarantees that it will pull the new file since it is in the link structure.

Comment: I said nothing about passing pare eyes to disrupt the cache, just changing the actual file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule for this redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?((?:css|js))/v\d+/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This seems to do nothing. Would I need to do anything else?

Comment: This worked on my Apache and redirected `www.localhost/js/v1/min/pages/myjs.js` to `www.localhost/js/min/pages/myjs.js` thus removing `/v1` from URL. Do you have other rules also? Try commenting out `<IfModule` and retest

Comment: This worked great! I had a type in my code and I was not adding v in front of my version. !

Comment: Glad it worked out. Strangely someone downvoted my working answer without any comment.