# Empty cache and hard reset using angular js programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, ionic-framework

Is there a way to achieve **Empty cache and hard reload** of browser using `angularjs` or `javascript` **programmatically**.

> I am not talking about clearing the cache of angularjs application but
>   the browsers using angularjs

[image: Empty cache and hard reset]

Comment: set `no-cache` header on server side where your application hosted..

Comment: i was wondering if there was a work around on the client side.

Comment: This is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850824/angularjs-force-browser-to-clear-cache (altough it doesn't have an answer at this moment in time)

Comment: clearing cache in angularjs application is onething, however i am talking about the whole browser empty cache and hard reload feature via angularjs, hope this clears the misunderstanding.

Comment: this also discuss this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922910/force-browser-to-clear-cache

Answer (score 2):

inject $templateCache in your main controller and execute once function X

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app.module.core').controller('LayoutCtrl', LayoutCtrl);
  LayoutCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$templateCache', '$cacheFactory'];

  function LayoutCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http,$templateCache, $cacheFactory) {

$scope.clearCache = function (){
        setTimeout(function() {
          $templateCache.removeAll();
               }, 5000);
 }()
```

Comment: Thanks have been looking for this for a while, works well !