# Ensuring Users Get Latest Javascript

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I would like to make sure users are getting the latest and greatest Javascript and CSS files. Is there a way to add a query string to the app.js to force the browser to pull down the latest version?

It is simple to automate the query string using a gulp task ie, compile my .js files into

```
app.js?v=10012015
```

But how do I then get this same query value into my index.html without having to manually add it each time I want to update the .js going out to users?

Comment: You don't really need to specify a version. just randomize the query and it will force the browser to download an uncached version.
The browser asks itself "do I know the file called app.js?v=whatever" if not, it will download the file again.

Comment: So if I have a file called app.js and I include a script with src="app.js?v=random" then the js file will be downloaded every time?

Comment: Well that would disable performance benefits from caching the rest of the time. I want to force the browser to re download js when I have actually updated the js file

Comment: I don't know how big your file is but it shouldn't be a problem. 
If you only want to download a new version whenever a new version is available, you will have to manually set the query whenever you change versions...

Comment: See, the browser doesn't know what version you have hosted on the server, it only knows if it knows the file name or not...

Comment: Consider minifying your file if you are worried about performance.

Comment: Also check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a gulp task called [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to look through my index.html and replace app.js with app.js?v=[TODAY'S DATETIME] so I get a unique query string every time I build my app. And this query string forces the browser to download the latest js file when I push a new build.