# How to override the javascript file when we logout the application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm doing changes in JavaScript file every time. I need to clear the browser history to reflects the changes in JavaScript file is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

Comment: Pressing CTRL + F5 in most browsers forces it to perform a cache refresh of the current page, including resources that the page loads such as JS files. Handy during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Just append some random value

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js?version=RANDOM VALUE'></script>
```

Comment: where i need to append that script tag

Comment: In the head section of your html page

Comment: for each and every page i need to add this script tag

Comment: If you want to refresh js file then yes.

Comment: thanks for your response Santosh

Comment: hi santosh.one small doute.if we move the code with above script tag to server.we will get any problem in code level

Comment: There is no problem.