# Change JS and CSS version of HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, version-control

I have recently created a project which has only html page and some JS files.

I want to versioning the JS and CSS files so it will load only when Dev has changed something inside it.

Before I was using Csthml page where I can easily do Versioning but in HTML I am unable to do so.

Is there any method or any process in which we can append version to my JS and CSS files

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

Comment: @Abhijeet how can I do versioning in html page. That is not helpful I already visited that link

Comment: Have you checked the second point in accepted answer

Comment: @Abhijeet I don't want to add version manually. How can I make it globally

Comment: Huppie mentioned that you need version control system to do that