# Not able to update my .js script after modifying it in AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJs. I started to write simple controller that will output Hello world!

**In my cribsControler.js code looked liked this:**

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('cribsController', function($scope){
            $scope.hello = 'hello world';
    });
```

and it worked. Then I changed my code to display details that are shown in the example below.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('ngCribs', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**cribsController.js**

```
angular
    .module('ngCribs')
    .controller('cribsController', function($scope){
            $scope.cribs = [
                {
                    "type": "condo",
                    "price": 22000,
                    "address": "nameOfStreet1",
                    "description": "description1"

                },
                {
                    "type": "hose",
                    "price": 54000,
                    "address": "nameOfStreet2",
                    "description": "description2"

                },
                {
                    "type": "cotage",
                    "price": 1000,
                    "address": "nameOfStreet3",
                    "description": "description3."

                }
                ];
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
<title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">
<pre>{{ cribs | json}}</pre>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
</html>
```

When I edited, saved, and than ran it in a browser I got a blank page. When I clicked view page source and then when I clicked on my script link: `<script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>`, I can see that it didn't update from "Hello World" to the display details.

What can I do to actually update it? Or maybe there is error in my code?

Comment: try to clear your browser cache.....make sure that your data is saved

Comment: Delete `module('ngCribs')` from cribsController.js. Simply leave angular.controller part and its logic. You have already declared the app's name in the app.js.

Comment: @stormec56, there is nothing wrong with doing that. Removing the module line will most likely break it in fact.

Comment: Why will it break it? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary it was cache when I cleaned it worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: @SiHa thanks for edit. :)

Comment: @user3599620.your welcome......there are minor things please take of these next time

Answer (score 0):

I development phase you should have the development console up. Press f12 to open It. Somewhere in the console you will find a setting that says something like: clear cache whille console is open(depends on which browser you use). Browser cache JavaScript files by default

Comment: great, but a correction from me. The setting should be something like:disable cache when dev console is open. If you use the operation clear cache you might loose cached data from other applications