# How to Clear the cache automatically for our clients only when we release a new version?

Tags: caching, release

We have an asp.net web based product. We want to clear the cache automatically for our clients only when we release a new version so that it is ensured that the new files such as javascript files are loaded. This is because we faced major issues with the client after last release due to cached files.
What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Make sure your client supports a "clean cache" operation and then the client should check what is the version upon every request and once it's changed: update the version locally (into a locally stored file/sqlite/whatever persistent storage you have available) and clear the cache.

Comment: Possible duplicatie of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files) SO question.