# update index.html in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, nginx

Currently our website in angularjs is not updated by latest javascript version without doing hard refresh is browser. In order to update it on real time basis, we have started sending a custom header (APP-VERSION) in our rest API based on which we can reload the page which results in updating the website by latest javascript version.
This version comparision code is written in javascript is the HTTP interceptor which is not updated on client side. 
In order to update index.html, we have tried various scenario which are as follows:-
1.We have changed the name of index.html to default.html but still it is not updated on client side.
2.We have changed the path (/test/index.html) of index.html, still its not working.
3.We have used on-page script on every page, we got a warning "Trying to load angularjs twice".
4.We have added the custom header (add_header Cache-Control no-cache;) in the config file on nginx which is also not working/

Please help us how to forcefully update the index.html on client side.

Please find the code index.html, HTTPInterceptor, and route.js

index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/WebRupee/2.0/font.min.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mrConsultant.min.css?ver=@@cssVer">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/preLoginPartner.css"> -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
@@gtmScript
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak layout="column">

    <div flex layout="column">
        <div ng-view flex layout="column"></div>
    </div>

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
@@gtmNoScript
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

</body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mrConsultant.min.js?ver=@@jsVer"></script>
<!--<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.timezones.min.js" ></script>-->
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js" async></script>-->
<script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<noscript>test scritp</noscript>
</html>
```

HTTPInterceptor:-

```
myApp.factory('HTTPInterceptor', ['$location','$q','API_URL','version','CookieService','$templateCache','$window',function ($location,$q,API_URL,version,CookieService,$templateCache,$window) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            if ((config.url.indexOf('.html') ==-1) && (config.url.indexOf('.svg')==-1)) {
                config.url = API_URL + config.url;
                if ((config.url.indexOf('/forgot-password-consultant')==-1) && (config.url.indexOf('/reset-password-consultant')==-1)) {

                    config.headers['Authorization'] = CookieService.getCookie('AUTH_TOKEN');
                }

                config.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.refer.v1+json";
            }
            return config;
        },
        'response': function (resp) {
            function createCustomAlert() {
                d = document;
                if(d.getElementById("website-update")) return;

                mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
                mObj.id = "website-update";
                style = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("style"));
                style.innerHTML = "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto')";

                alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
                alertObj.id = "website-update-card";

                h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
                h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode("UPDATE ALERT"));

                msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
                msg.innerHTML = "A new version of Refer is available now. Update now for better performance.";
                msg1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
                msg1.innerHTML = "If you are on an important task, continue your work and you can update on next page.";

                updateBtn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("button"))
                updateBtn.id = "website-update-btn";
                updateBtn.innerHTML = "Update Now";
                updateBtn.onclick = function() { clearTemplateCache();return true; }

                notUpdateBtn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("button"))
                notUpdateBtn.id = "website-update-notnow";
                notUpdateBtn.innerHTML = "Not now";
                notUpdateBtn.onclick = function() { removeCustomAlert();return false; }
            }

            function removeCustomAlert() {
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("website-update"));
            }

            function clearTemplateCache() {
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("website-update"));
                $templateCache.removeAll();
                $window.location.reload();
            }

            if (resp.status === 401) {
                $templateCache.removeAll();
                $window.location.reload();
                $location.path('/logout');
            }/*else if(resp.status === 200 && resp.headers('app-version') != null && resp.headers('app1-version') != version){
                createCustomAlert();
            }*/
            return resp;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 401) {
                $templateCache.removeAll();
                $location.path('/logout');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HTTPInterceptor');
}]);
```

route.js:-

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true,
            rewriteLinks: true
        });
    }

    $routeProvider.when('/unicorn-:startups-:consultant-:register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/registerCampaign.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'registerCtrl'

    }).when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegisterController',
        controllerAs: 'registerCtrl'

    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login3.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/jobs')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/forgot-password', {
        templateUrl: 'views/forgotPassword.html',
        controller: '' +
        'forgotPasswordController'

    }).when('/reset-password/:token/:sm', {
        templateUrl: 'views/resetPassword.html',
        controller: 'resetPasswordController'

    }).when('/logout', {
        resolve: {
            auth: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                UserService.logout();
                $location.path('/login');
                $location.replace();
            }]
        }
    }).when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/dashboard')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard1.html',

        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/dashboard')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/jobs/:jobType', {
        templateUrl: 'views/jobs.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/jobs.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/job-detail/:jobId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/job-detail.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/job-detail.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/direct-apply/:jobId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/apply-new.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/apply-new.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/performance', {
        templateUrl: 'views/performance.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/performance')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/calendar', {
        templateUrl: 'views/calender.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/calendar')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/tracker', {
        templateUrl: 'views/tracker.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/tracker')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/internal-jobs', {
        templateUrl: 'views/internal-jobs.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/internal-jobs')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/assigned-jobs', {
        templateUrl: 'views/assigned-jobs.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    $location.path('/assigned-jobs')
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/suggested-candidates/:jobId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/suggested-candidates.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/suggested-candidates.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/suggested-apply/:jobId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/apply-suggested.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/apply-suggested.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }



    }).when('/edit-candidate/:jobId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/edit-candidate.html',

        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/edit-candidate.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]
        }

    }).when('/database', {
        templateUrl: 'views/database.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/database.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]

        }

    }).when('/database-search', {
        templateUrl: 'views/database-search.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/database-search.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]

        }

    }).when('/database-search-result', {
        templateUrl: 'views/database-search-result.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/database-search-result.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]

        }

    }).when('/review-compare', {
        templateUrl: 'views/review-compare.html',
        resolve: {
            userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                if (UserService.session()) {
                    templateUrl: 'views/review-compare.html'
                } else {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }]

        }

    }).when('/add-new', {
            templateUrl: 'views/add-contact.html',
            resolve: {
                userInfo: ['$location', 'UserService', function ($location, UserService) {
                    if (UserService.session()) {
                        templateUrl: 'views/add-contact.html'
                    } else {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }]
            }

        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

}]);

myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$templateCache', function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
}]);
```

nginx settings:-

```
    location / {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    root   D:\refer-workspace\consultant_web;       
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html/ =404;
    expires -1;

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The version number must be set on server side like a constant `<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?v=NUMBER"></script>` so that whenever you can change the version number you can force the browser to get latest version as browser thinks their is a change in the file, thats how cdn's works. Refer this for more  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files

Comment: Please refer the above code. Version for js is already set in index.html. But it is working only on hard refresh in angularjs (Single page application). This is because index.html is loaded once when the website is opened browser. It is not working in website is already opened in browser. That means JS version is not updated in real time.

Comment: I have seen them, Did you got the @@jsVer and @@cssVer from server or you put it in fontend?

Comment: I want to forcefully download the index.html (Preferablly on logged out) on client side so that the JS version is updated on client side. That means when I get an 404 in response from server side then it will redirect to logout and the index.html will be forcefully updated on the client side.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mrConsultant.min.css?ver=@@cssVer">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mrConsultant.min.js?ver=@@jsVer"></script>

Comment: @@cssVer and @@jsVer are replaced by some number which I have placed in the browser.

Comment: let say you store @@version in localStorage, whenever you do logout you are updating those numbers?

Comment: Yes these versions are on the frontend. Drawback of such version is that it will work only when html is downloaded. But in my case HTML file containing css and js version will not be downloaded when the website is already opened in browser. I want to download that file forcefully only once so that my latest JS will be updated on client side.

Comment: I want to forcefully download the index.html (Preferably on logged out) on client side so that the JS version is updated on client side. That means when I get an 404 in response from server side then it will redirect to logout and the index.html will be forcefully updated on the client side by using nginx.