# How to add version number to JS file (because it loading old data in web from js file)

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask

JS example:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/openchat.js') }}"></script>
```

I've noticed that when i inspect source in web browser i see some of website like this  `myscript.js?er2dfsdsfsdf44455230099`
my file structure

[image]

i did lots of google, but i can't found any proper answer.
can anyone help on this.

Comment: your_file.js?<your_version> answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files)

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>` this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of i am using flask `url_for` method to call JS files, so i found a manual solution for adding version in my JS or CSS files. I found this

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/openchat.js' , v='14') }}"></script>
```

but i want to find automate method for this thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating the scripts tag dynamically could help you. Please try this

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const filenames = ["myscript.js", "myotherscript.js"];
    const body = document.body;

    for (const filename of filenames) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");

      script.src = `${filename}?${Date.now()}`;
      script.type = "javascript";

      body.appendChild(script);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i try your code it not showing anything in console and not loading

Comment: For this script to go into the context of your question you need to test it in an html document. How have you tried it?

Comment: Are you sure this code works because is not showing anything

Comment: it should not show anything, inspect the dom, it should have added just before closing the body tag a script tag for each script in the filenames array plus the timestamp that would make your script have a different src every time you visit the page

Comment: I added there only but it not taking JS files into the load

Comment: It is only an example, it should not load anything, it just shows how you can add a number in this case the timestamp to the file name, the way I propose is to create the script tags programmatically, this way I think you will avoid the problem you describe in your question

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you just need to hard reload your web browser. Search on the internet how to hard reload you're web browser. Because I don't know your browser I can't tell you right now.

Comment: yes hard rest is working but i but to implement in code so i don't have to do hard reset every time

Comment: "ctrl +F5 " for hard reset for PC but what will happen when i am on mobile device?

Comment: I think you can do inspect element in mobile device and hard reload from there

Comment: but if someone else using my website so i can't tell them to do hard reset on your web browser.

Comment: Well you can't but nobody should be using your website if its in dev mode. If they are trying to debug you can somehow contact them.

Comment: You can always push it to GitHub and run your code from there too

Comment: yeah correct but i have  to show them using Heroku so i have to deploy on Heroku

Comment: i have using PostgreSQL and other add-on in Heroku  so now i can't do changes in  deploy server

Comment: If you are showing someone then just run a hard reset, and the first time they open the code they will have the latest version

Comment: yeah i agree with that but it is a temp. solution but i want know about JS versioning system that many people are using .

Comment: Ok let me look into it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files I think maybe this can help you