# Equivalent to wildcards in Flask's url_for?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am developing a Flask application, and have it set so that my app's CSS file is generated with a random name via this build script:

```sh
rm style/main-*.css;
KEY=`tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 6`;
postcss build ./style/src/main.css -o ./style/main-$KEY.css
```

This is mostly for cache-related reasons; but it regardless results in a name with the wildcard pattern `main-*.css`
Since this name is randomized every build, I do not want to edit the template I include it in. Unfortunately, wildcards do not appear to work in Flask, as this:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet" href='{{ url_for('static', filename='style/main-*.css') }}'>
```

… does nothing (except, of course, yield a 404).
Is there a way to do this kind of behavior via Flask? Thank you.

Comment: A more common way to force a cache to update stylesheets/js/etc...is with a version parameter. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427/4032503).

Comment: better use the same url but with random parameter or with current timestamp or date and time ie. `main.css?2021.02.11_02.28.58` And this way you don't have to change url in template but you have to add function which always add different parameter to url.

Comment: Nice idea @furas, however I was in the process of implementing it (since it was simpler) when I thought of a kink: if the user's browser caches a different url every time it loads a page, that can fill up their cache. At least with my method there's only a new url if the CSS was updated, making it more efficient for the end-user — and not any different for me. Either way, it's a hack.

Comment: you can always use variable with the same value and change this variable only when you update `main.css` - you could even use function which get file time of creation for this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function and add it to the jinja2 environment as a global function.

```
import os
from glob import glob
from flask import current_app

def glob_assets(target):
    root = current_app.static_folder
    return [f[len(root)+1:] for f in glob(os.path.join(root, target))]

app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_assets=glob_assets)
```

Then you can add the stylesheets to the template within one iteration.

```
{% for css in get_assets('style/main-*.css') -%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=css) }}">
{% endfor -%}
```