# File in ubuntu webroot not updating - cached?

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, caching

I've been having a recurring issue with a jsfuns.js file in my ubuntu webroot. It is, as the name implies, a file for javascript functions, and is used only as an include in html/php scripts. Occasionally, when I replace the file with an updated version, this update isn't registered: class properties are unchanged from the previous version, new functions are not recognized as existing, etc, as if the old file still persists in a cache somewhere. So far this problem has happened only with this particular file, and it is intermittent.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23156/can-i-safely-remove-var-cache seems to confirm my suspicions re: potential caching, but but removing the cache folder and rebooting the server didn't resolve this issue.

I also searched the entire file path for another jsfuns.js script that could be taking precedence, but found nothing.

A workaround is simply to change the name of the file - everything works as expected as soon as I do this, but I'd rather understand what is the source of this problem.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/how-can-i-force-clients-to-refresh-javascript-files?rq=2

and I'm an idiot :)